# Output data to abuffersrc and pull from abuffersink with multiple inputs using FFMPEG afir filter

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I want to understand why `av_buffersink_get_frame()` always return `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`.
I use this algorithm:

1. Open input file `input.mp3`, create decoder for input file
2. Open signal file `signal.wav`, create decoder for signal file
3. Create filter graph and inputs/outputs with function `avfilter_graph_parse2("[in0][in1]afir[out], &inputs, &outputs")`
4. Create `abuffersrc` for every inputs with names "in0", "in1"
5. Create one `abuffersink` for one `outputs` with name "out"
6. Read and decode samples with methods `av_read_frame()`, `avcodec_send_packet()`, `avcodec_receive_frame()`, put samples to abuffersrc with `av_buffersrc_add_frame()` and trying to read samples from abuffersink with `av_buffersink_get_frame()` - HERE I get `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` for every call

Please, help!

I've tried to read all samples and push its to abuffersrc for `input` and `signal` pipes in first step and and call `av_buffersink_get_frame` one time in second step. I got `AVERROR(EGAIN)` again.

I've tried to config two outputs with names "in0" and "in1" and one input with name "out" and call `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr()` as done in here:

```
static AVFilterContext *init_buffersrc(AVCodecContext *decoder, AVFilterGraph *filter_graph, const char *pad_name) {
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc = NULL;
    uint8_t args[1024];

    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
        "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%"PRIx64"",
        decoder->time_base.num, decoder->time_base.den, decoder->sample_rate, av_get_sample_fmt_name(decoder->sample_fmt), decoder->channel_layout);

    CHECK_AV(avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc, avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer"), pad_name, args, NULL, filter_graph));
    return buffersrc;
}

static AVFilterContext *init_buffersink(AVFilterGraph *filter_graph) {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink = NULL;

    CHECK_AV(avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink, avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink"), "out", NULL, NULL, filter_graph));
    return buffersink;
}

static void init_complex_graph(const char *desc, Context *ctx) {

    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut **outputs = (AVFilterInOut**) av_malloc(ctx->nb_input_files*sizeof(AVFilterInOut *));
    char *dump;
    uint8_t pad_name[64];

    filter_graph = ctx->filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    filter_graph->nb_threads = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i< ctx->nb_input_files; ++i) {
        outputs[i] = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ctx->nb_input_files; ++i) {
        AVFilterContext *buffersrc;
        snprintf(pad_name, sizeof(pad_name), "in%d", i);        
        buffersrc = init_buffersrc(ctx->input_files[i]->decoder, filter_graph, pad_name);
        ctx->input_files[i]->buffersrc = buffersrc;
        outputs[i]->name = av_strdup(pad_name);
        outputs[i]->filter_ctx = buffersrc;
        outputs[i]->pad_idx = 0;
        if (i == ctx->nb_input_files - 1) {
            outputs[i]->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            outputs[i]->next = outputs[i + 1];
        }
    }

    ctx->output_file->buffersink = init_buffersink(filter_graph);

    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = ctx->output_file->buffersink;
    inputs->pad_idx =0;
    inputs->next = NULL;

    CHECK_AV(avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, desc, &inputs, outputs, NULL));

    CHECK_AV(avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL));
}   

// Call init_complex_graph("[in0][in1]afir[out]", SOME_CONTEXT);
```

and still nothing.